# Xamarin EnvVar for osx output folder path of native libs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, msbuild

When using native libs directly added to the app project, if we set the build action as `None`, but set "Always copy to output folder", the static native libs seem to get copied to the Caches-folder(eg: `/Users/<uname>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/<app-name>/<identifier>/`) as expected to then link via the `${ProjectDir}` env-var for mTouchExtraArgs. Can see this being achieved via a step in `Xamarin.Apple.Sdk.targets`.

`<!-- For backwards compatibility, we also copy the None items with CopyToOutput to the root build directory in the mac -->
<_NoneWithCopyToOutputDirectory Include="@(_NoneWithTargetPath)" Condition="'%(_NoneWithTargetPath.CopyToOutputDirectory)' != ''" />`

This does include the .a files in the final .app package I guess which becomes a separate issue but this works at least to get the app working.

However, if I similarly add a native file to an iOS project via a nuget package MSBuild targets file, it does not get copied to the build cache root folder(tried setting the file Item type to Content and was same result). Although it still is transferred into `<cache folder path>/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone7.2-11.0.2/` folder(guessing as part of the Always copy to output flag) which is where the .app for the application seems to also be in.

I'm just looking for some way to pass this path to the mTouchExtraArgs.

**Note:** Issue doesnt exist with iPhoneSimulator as output path merely is `<cache folder>/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug`, so I was able to just use `${ProjectDir}/bin/$(Platform)/$(Configuration)/mylib.a`, to have this work in the simulator. It links fine and works as expected then.

For devices however that last part of the path being dynamic based on device, not sure how I can indicate that value to the linker. Any help with this would be great.

Using Visual Studio (2017 15.3.5) and latest stable Xamarin.iOS(11.0), Xamarin(4.7.9.45) if it helps.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not adding the lib as `Native Reference` to the `Xamarin.iOS` project?

Comment: @SushiHangover cos thats what the documentation states it requires https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/#Linking_Your_Library in Android it asks for `AndroidNativeLibrary`, and iOS it asks for build action of `None`, but going to try this out as well, if it makes any difference here since `Content` didnt do much either

Comment: @SushiHangover there isnt a `Native Reference` build action. tried with `EmbeddedResource` such as `<EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)mylib.a">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </EmbeddedResource>` and doesnt copy the file to the root of the cache folder either. It does move it to the path I've specified in the question, so its not like the targets file was ignored or something, just isnt moving the file to the cache folder root for whatever reason regardless of BuildAction of `None` or `Content` or now `EmbeddedResource`

Comment: Those directions are a "little" outdated ;-)  Add it as a `Native Reference` and set its `Kind` property, enable `Smart Link` and `Force Load`, etc...

Comment: It is not a build action, it is a custom `ItemGroup` in the project that includes a `NativeReference` section and the flags for `mtouch`. Just Drag/drop the lib into the **Native Reference** group of the `Xamarin.iOS` project and then set its properties

Comment: @SushiHangover aha outdated docs it is then :) got what you meant with the `NativeReference` and that seems to have done the trick indeed. Do you want to post it as an answer and I'll accept it? Also if you dont mind can you say how the linker flags should be passed. Currently even with your fix I'm passing it such as `  <PropertyGroup>
    <MtouchExtraArgs>-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -llib1 -llib2 -lresolv"</MtouchExtraArgs>
  </PropertyGroup>` just removed the force load portion considering its coming via the Native Reference itself but guess I should be doing the same for linker flag too?

Comment: I added an answer. you can continue to use the `gcc_flags` as required for your library, but items link `-L${ProjectDir}` will be handled, so you could just add `-llib1 -llib2 -lresolv` to the linker flags property and remove the `MtouchExtraArgs`, up to you... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directions are a "little" outdated ;-)

Add the framework or static/dynamic library as a "Native Reference" and set its `mtouch/gcc_flags` properties. This can be done by drag/dropping the framework directory or the library into the `Native Reference` group of the `Xamarin.iOS` project.

[image]

You can then set the properties for the **`Kind`** of library is it: Framework, static or dynamic.

[image]

The other properties are fairly self-explanatory if you know the gcc link options and *somewhat* covered in the existing "Linking" docs:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/#Linking_Your_Library

This will produce a custom `ItemGroup` / `NativeReference` in the project that the `Xamarin.iOS` MSBuild target will parsed and forwarded to `mtouch`.

Example from SushiHangover.SVGKit:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="..\SVGKit\DerivedData\SVGKit-iOS\Build\Products\Release-universal\libSVGKit-iOS.2.0.0.a">
      <Kind>Static</Kind>
      <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
      <Frameworks>CocoaLumberjack CoreText CoreImage QuartzCore CoreGraphics</Frameworks>
      <LinkerFlags>-lxml2</LinkerFlags>
    </NativeReference>
    <NativeReference Include="..\SVGKit\3rd-party-frameworks\CocoaLumberjack-2.2.0\iOS\CocoaLumberjack.framework">
      <Kind>Framework</Kind>
      <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
    </NativeReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Re: https://github.com/sushihangover/SVGKit.Binding